# Aggregate by custom defined buckets, according to field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm interested in aggregating my data into buckets, but I want to put two distinct values to the same bucket.

This is what I mean:

Say I have this query:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "my-agg-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ecs.version"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it returns this response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "my-agg-name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1.12.0",
          "doc_count" : 642826144
        },
        {
          "key" : "8.0.0",
          "doc_count" : 204064845
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.1.0",
          "doc_count" : 16508253
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.0.0",
          "doc_count" : 9162928
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.6.0",
          "doc_count" : 1111542
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.5.0",
          "doc_count" : 10445
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

every distinct value of the field `ecs.version` is in it's own bucket.

But say I wanted to define my buckets such that:
bucket1: [1.12.0, 8.0.0]
bucket2: [1.6.0, 8.4.0]
bucket3: [1.0.0, 8.8.0]

Is this possible in anyway?

I know I can just return all the buckets and do the sum programmatically, but this list can be very long, I don't think it would be efficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: you want total count for [1.12.0, 8.0.0] in bucket1 right ?

Comment: Please check  my answer and marked as solution if it really helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runtime Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) to generat runtime field and that field will be use for aggregation. I have done below exmaple on ES 7.16.

I  have index some of the sample document and below is aggregation output without join on multipul values:

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "version" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1.12.0",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.6.0",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "8.4.0",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "8.0.0",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can use below query with runtime mapping but you need to add multipul if condition for your version mappings:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "normalized_version": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": """
        String version = doc['version.keyword'].value;
        if (version.equals('1.12.0') || version.equals('8.0.0')) {
          emit('1.12.0, 8.0.0');
        } else if (version.equals('1.6.0') || version.equals('8.4.0')){
          emit('1.6.0, 8.4.0');
        }else {
           emit(version);
        }
      """
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "normalized_version"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is output of above aggregation query:

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "genres" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1.6.0, 8.4.0",
          "doc_count" : 6
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.12.0, 8.0.0",
          "doc_count" : 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```